# How to get updated data from a table after selecting from dropdown using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the data from a html table that seems to load data on a table based on the value of dropdown (with a default value). However, when I do the selenium click() on the dropdown, the table values change but the data I get is still from the old page. How do I get the updated values instead? Here, is the code I've tried.

Note: The URL I'm trying for example is [this one](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/aston-villa-chelsea-Ea6xur9j/?r=1#over-under;2)

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)     # you can use the url linked above for example

if browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'//a[@id = "user-header-oddsformat-expander"]/span').text != 'IN Odds':
 # choose a type of odd that you want from the top dropdown menu
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//a[@id = "user-header-oddsformat-expander"]').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//ul[@id = "user-header-oddsformat"]/li/a/span[contains(text(), "IN Odds")]').click()

browser.implicitly_wait(10)
table = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#odds-data-table')

for elem in table:
    print elem.text
```

Here, even after performing the click() before dong find_elements...(), I still get the data from the originally loaded table, not the new one. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for "In Odds" to be the dropdown value using [`text_to_be_present_in_element()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/aston-villa-chelsea-Ea6xur9j/?r=1#over-under;2"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get(url)

if browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'//a[@id = "user-header-oddsformat-expander"]/span').text != 'IN Odds':
 # choose a type of odd that you want from the top dropdown menu
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//a[@id = "user-header-oddsformat-expander"]').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//ul[@id = "user-header-oddsformat"]/li/a/span[contains(text(), "IN Odds")]').click()

    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//a[@id = "user-header-oddsformat-expander"]/span'), "IN Odds"))


table = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#odds-data-table')
for elem in table:
    print(elem.text)
```